# Actualizar Archivo de nodeJS sin detener reiniciar

Tags: javascript, nodejs

¿Habrá una forma de actualizar un archivo y ver los cambios en tiempo real?

**ejemplo**

> tengo un archivo `server.js` y lo modifico.

¿como hago que se vea el resultado sin detener el servicio y reiniciarlo con `node server.js`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes usar nodemon, el cual es un demonio de node para correr el servidor, con ello cada vez que haya cambios se actualizará sin tener que reiniciar el servidor, lo instalas:

```
npm install -g --save nodemon
```

despues lo corres:

```
nodemon server.js
```

y listo.

Comment: It is necessary to take into account that the nodemon does not prevent the server from being restarted. Conversely. executes an automatic and controlled restart. but if you have a request in progress at the time nodemon restart is executed it will simply be lost.
- If the question is how to make changes and see these reflected in my server automatically. (Nodemon is the answer).

Answer (score 1):

Como bien te ha respondido Lius Angel puedes utilizar nodemon, pero para que no tengas que ejecutar la orden cada vez en la consola, lo que puedes hacer es incluirlo los script de inicio en package.json. Te explico con un ejemplo.

Package.json:

```
"name": "api-restful-ejemplo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "API de ejemplo",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon index.js",   <---- Si te fijas, esto ha sido incluido posrteriormente.
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
```

De esta forma cada vez que realices un guardado de tu código, se actulizará.
Espero haberte sido de ayuda.
Un saludo.

Comment: ¿Para qué lo agrego en el scrips si lo puedo correr con el comando?

Comment: Si tu incluyes la clave "start" en el script, podras ejecutar tu aplicación con el comando "npm start", lo cual, en este caso, hará que nodemon comience a ejecutar index.js, y registrará cada cambio automaticamente, sin que tu tengas que volver a ejecutar ningún comando. Si existe algún error te lo notificará. Espero haberlo explicado más o menos bien para que te puedas haber enterado, cualquier duda, ya sabes.

Comment: Gracias H. Díaz, esa explicación la hubieras aplicado en tu respuesta, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Es un poco tarde, pero se que a alguno le podrá ayudar.
Si desea evitar que el servidor se reinicie cada que guarda los cambios hechos en archivos **JS** del lado del cliente, puede configurar **nodemon** para que ignore esos archivos.

En su archivo **package.json** agregue esto:

```
"nodemonConfig": {
    "ignore": [
      "public/*" <---- aquí su carpeta public con los archivos estáticos
    ]
  }
```